# Easiest way to locate a static variable in code?

Tags: c++, variables, search, static-initialization, launch-time

I have a bug on my plate to locate and rewrite a static variable in one of our libraries that is taking up launch time in our application. I am not familiar with the library code base and am asking for good heuristics/techniques/grep commands/etc. that would ease my task in identifying the location of said static variable?

(P.S. I'm already searching the code base for `static`; needless to say it's a verbose result.)

Update: The bug report simply states "library XYZ takes N ms at static initialization"; I do not have any more information about the static variable than that. I don't have the profiling logs but I'll see if I can get them from the bug reporter.

Comment: Perhaps it's a dumb question, but I'm also assuming that you don't know the name of the static variable--just that "one" exists?

Comment: How do you know the time is because of this static variable - presumably you have some logs or profile runs - if so what do these logs etc as that will give more things to look for

Comment: `grep "static <type_of_variable_here>"` might narrow down your results a bit, if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: Question updated; thanks for the comments

Comment: A global variable need not be staic. I would say you need to expand your search to extern variables.

Comment: @Martin York: Ah, a good point, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to do a `nm -aC <libname>` first and grep by the static and global vars (IIRC they should be prefixed with a B/b or a T/t), then look for those vars in the source code. It may narrow down the haystack a little.

Comment: Exact command which helps me `nm -aC <libname> | grep -E ' [Bb] ' | less -N`